# How to hide categories with no urls in them in while loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to hide all categories that has no links in them. Basically, what I have is table of all possible categories and unique ID for each category, second table contains all widgets that have parent page ID assigned to each widget. Parent page ID is an ID of the relevant category item (name if you will).

Now my problem, with the script that you can see below, everything works fine except for one thing, all category items are being displayed even when they have no links in them, I do understand the reason why, but cannot figure out the way to sort it all out.

Please help

```
    $category_topic_query = 'SELECT * FROM lcategories ORDER BY ID asc';
    $resc = $db->prepare($category_topic_query);
    $resc->execute();
    $template_link_query = "SELECT parentpageID, ImagePath, referring_url, templateTitle FROM Files WHERE parentpageID = :id AND pageID = '0'";
    $link_res = $db->prepare($template_link_query);

while ($category_topic = $resc -> fetch()){
    $category_topic_ID = $category_topic['ID'];
    $category_topic_name = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $category_topic['category_name']);
    $category_topic_url = DST.$category_topic['category_folder'].DS.$category_topic['category_page'];
    $link_res->execute(array(':id' => $category_topic_ID));


print<<<END
<h3><a href="$category_topic_url">$category_topic_name</a></h3>
<ul class="arrow">

END;

while ($t_links = $link_res -> fetch()){
    $templateID = $t_link['parentpageID'];
    $links_array = '<li><a href="'.DST.$t_links['ImagePath'].DS.$t_links['referring_url'].'">'.$t_links['templateTitle'].'</a></li>';

print<<<END
$links_array

END;
}
print<<<END
</ul>

END;
}
```

Thank for your time.

Comment: Use a single query with an `INNER JOIN` between `lcategories` and `Files`. Any categories that don't match will be omitted from the results.

Comment: IF you do not mind, can you please put your suggestion in Answer preferably with little explanation on how to do it. My knowledge as you have probably guessed is a bit limited, I am only learning it all. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would if I had the time, but I'm about to leave.

Comment: OK, I could wait until tomorrow if that is ok?

Comment: Sure, but why don't you use the time to try to figure it out yourself? That's how you learn, not by having answers spoon-fed to you.

Comment: THis is what I am doing right now, just thought it would be a bit of help to me, but I agree, it will be better to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single query joins both tables, so it only returns rows from `lcategories` that have matches in `Files`. It's ordered by `parentpageID`, which is the same as the category ID, so that all rows in the same category will be together in the results. Then the fetch loop notices when this ID changes, and prints the category header at that time.

```
$query = "SELECT l.category_name, l.category_folder, l.category_page,
                 f.parentpageID, f.ImagePath, f.referring_url, f.templateTitle
          FROM lcategories l
          INNER JOIN Files f ON f.parentpageID = l.ID
          WHERE f.pageID = '0'
          ORDER BY f.parentpageID";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$last_topic = null;
$first_row = true;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $category_topic_ID = $row['parentpageID'];
    if ($category_topic_ID !== $last_topic) {
        $category_topic_name = htmlentities($row['category_name']);
        $category_topic_url = DST.$row['category_folder'].DS.$row['category_page'];
        if (!$first_row) {
            print "</ul>\n;";
            $first_row = false;
        }
        print<<<END
<h3><a href="$category_topic_url">$category_topic_name</a></h3>
<ul class="arrow">

END;
        $last_topic = $category_topic_ID;
    }
    $links_array = '<li><a href="'.DST.$row['ImagePath'].DS.$row['referring_url'].'">'.$row['templateTitle'].'</a></li>';

    print<<<END
    $links_array

    END;
}
print "</ul>\n";
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks, I figured it out, but really thanks, the part that I was confused about was the actual query string built up, but now I get it. Out of curiosity, how would you close the list tag after each cycle </ul>, I had to create another IF for it to work.

Comment: by the way, db does need $ in front of it :)

Comment: Sorry, missed the `</ul>`, I just added it. It does indeed need an `if` so it doesn't print it before the first `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if condition, and a [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to skip to have your loop skip to the next time.

```
while ($t_links = $link_res -> fetch()){
    $templateID = $t_link['parentpageID'];
    $links_array = '<li><a href="'.DST.$t_links['ImagePath'].DS.$t_links['referring_url'].'">'.$t_links['templateTitle'].'</a></li>';

// no like, so skip.
if (''==DST.$t_links['ImagePath'].DS.$t_links['referring_url']) continue;
print<<<END
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that does not solve the problem entirely, it gets rid of empty links inside the category, but does not get rid of the category name it self. Any idea of what could be done with it?